# Marionette.js - switch view template with event handler

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events

We're using Marionette.js and had hoped we could switch the active template of a Layout based on the resize of the window. However, it appears that the `getTemplate()` function is only called once when the view loads.

Is there a way to switch the current template after the Layout has loaded in Marionette? We have this code:

```
initialize: function() {
    //... other code
    this.windowWidth = 0;
    $(window).resize(this.resizeHandler);
},

getTemplate: function () {
    if (this.windowWidth <= 1050) {
      return "#small-screen-template"; 
    }
    return "#large-screen-template"; 
},

resizeHandler: function () {
    this.windowWidth = $(window).width();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not fully tested, but you could alter your initialize method to also include call to "render". Also, you should not forget about cleanup of event handlers.

Basically change initialize to this:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    //..
    this.windowWidth = 0;

    $(window).on("resize", this.resizeHandler);
    $(window).on("resize", this.render);       
}
```

And add cleanup method ([onClose](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#view-close) from marionette):

```
onClose: function() {
    $(window).off("resize", this.resizeHandler);
    $(window).off("resize", this.render);                
}
```

By doing this:

- when screen is resized windowWidth is correctly updated
- after that another callback is called, and it will re-render the view
- when view is closed, callbacks from window object are released

Should work in theory, not tested by any mean

Comment: Thanks, drax. The challenge isn't so much with calling the event handler -- it gets called on window.resize. However, the template isn't changing.

Comment: $(window).on("resize", this.render);  will do the trick. getTemplate is called inside render method of the view. Code basically re-renders view after resizeHandler takes care of setting the windowWidth property.